# Method local inner class hides method fields

Tags: java, inner-classes

Given the following class definition

```
public class MethodLocalAccess {

    int m = 10;

    String show(){
        final int m = 20;
        final int n = 30;
        class MyClass{
            int m = 40;
            String someOtherMethod(){
                return "" + m + n + this.m + MyClass.this.m + MethodLocalAccess.this.m;
            }
        }

        MyClass object = new MyClass();
        return object.someOtherMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MethodLocalAccess().show());
    }

}
```

Produces output `4030404010`, which is fairly established why. I want to know, if the local-variable `final int m = 20;` can be accessed inside the inner-class.

Other way around, fields declared in method-local inner-class having same name as that of method-local-variable, will permanently hide the latter.

Answer (score 2):

What are you referring to is called variable *shadowing* ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)).

> If a declaration of a type (such as a member variable or a parameter
>   name) in a particular scope (such as an inner class or a method
>   definition) has the same name as another declaration in the enclosing
>   scope, then the declaration shadows the declaration of the enclosing
>   scope. You cannot refer to a shadowed declaration by its name alone.

Once you shadowed a variable, it is not accessible anymore without explicitly specifying its scope, if possible. The only solution in this case is to rename either outer or inner variable.

Comment: However you can access top level variables with the context `this` even though they shadwoed.

Comment: @SureshAtta That is correct. It seems that OP grasped that already :)

Comment: I went through the link prior posting the question. But, the topic doesn't seem to throw enough light on method-local inner-class categorically.

Comment: @soufrk , Miljen missed to quote the last important line in the same paragraph. `You cannot refer to a shadowed declaration by its name alone.` Which mean that, if you can access the context you can refer it. Since the class have the context, your are allowed to do `this.xx` and since function doesn't have context and just the scope, you cannot refer it.

Comment: @SureshAtta Exactly.

Comment: @SureshAtta So, am I correct to interpret that the term `shadow` or `hide` is applicable when context overlaps. Since no such thing happens here it is not a case of shadowing. Rather, this is the behaviour of such class. Simple terms, `erosion of scope` maybe.

Comment: @soufrk Hiding is completely different.  Won't apply here. It is purely between parent and chilld.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The variable inside the function completely shadowed and you can't refer it anymore as Java doesn't have a way to refer function context.

However you can access top level variables with the context this even though they shadowed (*infact you are not shadowing and creating a local variable with same name*).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because it's shadowed.

You can't even with reflection, because reflection works on the type level, not on the byte-code.

You can, with additional tools, if you play with the generated byte-code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I don't think you can access the local variable `m` defined in the `show` method since you already have it declared in your inner class, therefore shadowing it.

Using constructs like `ClassName.this.varName` allows you to access only the members of that enclosing class. This means you can't use that type of expression to access shadowed local varibles defined in the method since they aren't members of that class.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, the fields declared in method-local inner-class having same name
  as that of method-local-variable, will permanently hide the latter.
- We can access the local-variable final int m = 20 inside the
  inner-class only if you don't have the instance variable of Myclass, 
  int m = 40 is absent.